# How to create an UDP Broadcast listener socket on Blackberry OS using WebWorks

Tags: sockets, blackberry, udp, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying to develop a **BlackBerry** app using **WebWorks SDK**. This application will have an UDP Broadcast socket that will listen to inconming UDP broadcast packets at port 8001.

Is this posible? Is there an available Javascript framework to do it?

I've found that node.js could create UDP broadcast socket but I think it is only available on Blackberry 10.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I would say it's *extremely unlikely* that this is possible in WebWorks since it is not possible using native Java development.

Comment: Oh! I don't know that. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Correct UDP is hardly supported in some OS versions only

Comment: My client said that it is possible to do it because he have done it on iOS and Android also. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Well if your client says something is possible it *must* be true ;-)